# Scrollable div for comments?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

I'd like to suggest that the *expanded* comment block be scrollable. Keep the existing "top 5 or so" / expand functionality, but when the comment block is expanded, make the comment section scrollable.

It'd also be prime if that scrollable section had a user-adjustable size similar to what's seen on the "original answer" section of the question edit page (see image below).

[image: Example Image]

Comment: "That thing" does not have any scrollbars in my Safari, and that actually renders it quite useless to me (but: holding down Command while clicking the back button is a good enough workaround for me if I need the question text). So, you want the expandable part of "that thing", but *with* scrollbars, right? (I actually prefer the no-scrollbar full expanded comments, just like it is right now, so I don't know why I even wonder what you want exactly.)

Comment: No, "that thing" doesn't have scrollbars; yes, I want "that thing", with scrollbars, on the comments section.

Comment: -1, not enough freehand circles!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds a bit self-contradicting to me.

the only reason I click the "show more comments" button is when I'm interested in reading *all* the comments, so forcing me to interact with a scrollbar (or something like it) to see them, *even after I've clicked a special button*, is precisely what I don't want.

In addition, maybe it's just me, but I have yet to seen a single post where the expanded comment block took more space than I would have accepted. Of course, what I accept and what others accept may be different, but we do need to take into account the severe limitation on comment length, which largely prevents insanely-large comment blocks.